# Should entity be specific to Intent of Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

For example **Intent cutoff** has training phrase - **ABC college cutoff**

- where ABC college is entity - *college*
- cutoff is - *collegedetail entity*

Now another **Intent exam** has training phrase - **ABC college exams**

- where ABC college is again entity - *college*
- exams is again- *collegedetail entity*

Here entities are meant to be same but Intents are different. But Dialogflow is confusing the intents every time because of same entities.

So my question is should entities be Intent specific or there is some other way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for the training phrases are meant to capture different values, all of which are valid *for that Intent*.

If the **Exam** intent has a training phrase "[ABC college][exams]" with each of those parts having an Entity, then it means that you're expecting different values for each part, the Entity reflects what those possible values should be, and you want to be able to find out what that specific value was.

It sounds like you're saying that the training phrase for the **Exam** Intent should be something more like "[ABC college] exams". So you have a parameter for the college being asked about, but you are expecting only "exams" to be a valid thing said for this Intent. You don't need to know exactly what that value was - you know its about exams because that's the purpose of all the training phrases for that Intent.